# Including /maintaining Space in Gsub with R

Tags: r, gsub

This is probably a basic question, and may have been answered, cannot find any direct post yet though:

Goal: To substitute specific words in a text/character vector with "" or with "1:n", ideally using gsub, open to other ideas as well.

Details: 
I ran a loop for gsub, which did the trick BUT it replaced every "i", when I want only the " i " (with space before and after to be replaced, retaining all other i's within words. So also for "to" - must replace only full word 
=> "i went to town indigo" must become "went town indigo", 
current code (in principle) makes it "went own nd go"
Any input would be appreciated, Thanks!

Here is the loop I wrote in R (again, probably outdated /inefficient):

```
a1 <- NULL
for(j in 1:length(xt1)) {
  for (i in 1:length(st1)) {

    xt1[j] = gsub(st1[i], " ", xt1[j])

  } 
  a1[j] = gsub(st1[i], " ", xt1[j])
}
head(a1)
```

st1

> st1
>    [1] "u"   "e"   "to"  "the" "a"   "and" "you" "for" "of"  "i"

xt1

> xt1
>   [1] "Nice to see Sofia Kenin get title No.5 in Lyon, especially so soon after her #AusOpen triumph. Always shows up for the tour events and battled hard, through four consecutive three-setters, to earn the title."
>   [2] "@KeepUKtogether @waltersboy_ Positive destinations for those leaving school are increasingly good. Many go into excellent apprenticeships such as those I met on Friday. Able to study and earn money at the same time. Win win."
>   [3] "@kamaalrkhan @iTIGERSHROFF Tiger has earn that much stardom to make film hit"
>   [4] "@ComfortablySmug Women only earn 23 hours to a man's 24. We need to end the hour gap in this country."
>   [5] "@ByMikeBaker @GlenBikes I think @MayorJenny wants to solve a bigger crisis so she looks good for elections! Or maybe theirs just too many donors counting the money they'll earn or lose based on the decision!"
>   [6] "Ravens dump Mustangs, earn another national final appearance"
>   [7] "@JaredRBLX Yeah this is my problem.. in my new build my staircase alone was over 10,000 it takes so long to earn  Then I lose motivation or ideas on what I'm doing.. So now saving before anymore building "
>   [8] "All i do is yearn a life without a concern, and dream of having a turn to earn money to burn mapping out my strategies to get rich. My desire is like a scratch that needs to get itched..."

a1

> head(a1)
>   [1] "N c    s   S    K n n g t t tl  No.5  n Lyon,  sp c  lly so soon  ft r h r #A sOp n tr  mph. Alw ys shows  p   th    r  v nts  nd b ttl d h rd, thro gh fo r cons c t v  thr  -s tt rs,     rn th  t tl ."
>   [2] "@K  pUK g th r @w lt rsboy_ Pos t v  d st n t ons   thos  l  v ng school  r   ncr  s ngly good. M ny go  n   xc ll nt  ppr nt c sh ps s ch  s thos  I m t on Fr d y. Abl    st dy  nd   rn mon y  t th  s m  t m . W n w n."
>   [3] "@k m  lrkh n @ TIGERSHROFF T g r h s   rn th t m ch st rdom   m k  f lm h t"
>   [4] "@Com t blySm g Wom n only   rn 23 ho rs     m n's 24. W  n  d    nd th  ho r g p  n th s co ntry."
>   [5] "@ByM k B k r @Gl nB k s I th nk @M yorJ nny w nts   solv    b gg r cr s s so sh  looks good    l ct ons! Or m yb  th  rs j st  o m ny donors co nt ng th  mon y th y'll   rn or los  b s d on th  d c s on!"
>   [6] "R v ns d mp M st ngs,   rn  noth r n t on l f n l  pp  r nc "

Comment: Inferior to the answers provided below, but still a tip, was able to use:               st <- paste("",st,"") and that led to each value in st having a space added before & after, that worked well with the nested loop & produced desired results. But I will be using the paste0("\\b"...  approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regex, `\b` is a "word boundary", basically a change from letters to non-letters (could be space, new line, punctuation at the end of a sentence, etc.). So, you need to put word boundaries on either side of your patterns.

We can also do better than a `for` loop---separating each of your patterns with `|` for OR, you can make all the replacements at once.

```
st1 = c("u", "e", "to", "the", "a", "and", "you", "for", "of", "i")

st1b = paste0("\\b", st1, "\\b", collapse = "|") ## adding extra \ for R

gsub(st1b, "", "i went to town indigo")
# [1] " went  town indigo"
```

This left extra spaces, which you can clean up with another `gsub(" +", "", x)`

Comment: Thanks - that worked! reminded me of the paste() vs paste0() as well! had tried adding \b, but did not use  ... collapse = "|"    - what does the collapse = "|" do? "or" for what?

Comment: Run `paste0("\\b", st1, "\\b")` and look at it, then run `paste0("\\b", st1, "\\b", collapse = "|")`, you can see what it does!

Comment: Great - that was what I was missing in an option I tried - solves "argument 'pattern' has length > 1" ~ Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from Gregor, you don't need a loop to make the replacements. You can use gsub or string_replace from the [stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/) package:

```
library(stringr)

st1 = c("u", "e", "to", "the", "a", "and", "you", "for", "of", "i")

st1b = paste0("\\b", st1, "\\b", collapse = "|") ## adding extra \ for R

xt1 <- c("Nice to see Sofia Kenin get title No.5 in Lyon, especially so soon after her #AusOpen triumph. Always shows up for the tour events and battled hard, through four consecutive three-setters, to earn the title.",
         "@KeepUKtogether @waltersboy_ Positive destinations for those leaving school are increasingly good. Many go into excellent apprenticeships such as those I met on Friday. Able to study and earn money at the same time. Win win.",
         "@kamaalrkhan @iTIGERSHROFF Tiger has earn that much stardom to make film hit",
         "@ComfortablySmug Women only earn 23 hours to a man's 24. We need to end the hour gap in this country.",
         "@ByMikeBaker @GlenBikes I think @MayorJenny wants to solve a bigger crisis so she looks good for elections! Or maybe theirs just too many donors counting the money they'll earn or lose based on the decision!",
         "Ravens dump Mustangs, earn another national final appearance",
         "@JaredRBLX Yeah this is my problem.. in my new build my staircase alone was over 10,000 it takes so long to earn Then I lose motivation or ideas on what I'm doing.. So now saving before anymore building ",
         "All i do is yearn a life without a concern, and dream of having a turn to earn money to burn mapping out my strategies to get rich. My desire is like a scratch that needs to get itched...")

a1 <- str_replace_all(xt1, st1b, "")

a1 <- gsub(st1b, "", xt1)
```

Comment: tried stringi & stringr before going down to nested loops, but was not setup correctly with \b and gave errors & NAs  - Your code works great - Thank You!  ......................     With    a1 <- gsub(st2, "", xt, ignore.case = T)     # added ignore.case = T, for example to exclude upper case i's.    [upvoted your answer, since I am a new user that may take time to update]